# Como criar um objeto e preencher com dados retornados do Firebse?

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript

[Gist Referente a pergunta](https://gist.github.com/yangoff/cfe67daf27d2e075ef009ced38d1cf24)

Tenho uma classe event,e um metodo q se chama snapdbEventos(), porem quando coloco o objeto la dentro e tento definir os valores das variaveis no objeto ocorre o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Print do DB

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você ja verificou se a propriedade id tem algum valor? pelo erro ela esta undefined ou seja sem um tipo definido

Comment: Sim,eu consigo imprimir todos os dados no console.

Comment: em vez de utilizar snapshot.key no id tenta colocar uma string manualmente só para teste então

Comment: Tentei e deu a mesma coisa,o problema e com esta classe

Comment: porque o no id `id?:string` tem a interrogação e nos outros nao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando for atribuir os valores na classe é recomendando usar funções setters ou um construtor, por exemplo:

```js
class export Evento {
  id: string;
  horaInicio: string;
  horaFim: string;
  
  constructor(values: Object) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
    // Ou
    this.id = values.id;
    this.horaInicio = values.horaInicio;
    this.horaFim = values.horaFim;
  }
  
  setHoraInicio(horaInicio) {
    this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
  }
  
  setHoraFim(horaFim) {
    this.horaFim = horaFim;
  }

}
```

e no seu método de atribuição no component ou provider:

```js
private evento:Evento

chamaAPI() {
  apiService.getEventos().subscribe(res => {
    this.evento = new Evento(res.evento);
  });
}
```